# How uninstall visual studio 2015 completely and install 2013 instead

Tags: visual-studio, list, visual-studio-2015

How can I uninstall my Visual Studio 2015 completely and and install Visual Studio 2013 instead?
I think i have to uninstall some components after uninstalling my Visual Studio 2015 but i don't know which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you'd want to do this... but it's not too hard.

To uninstall Visual Studio 2015 from a Windows machine, just run this command in CMD (credit to imarktu):

```
D:\vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /forc
```

The link to install Visual Studio 2013 is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44914

Comment: I guess i have to change that "D:\vs_ultimate.exe". Am i right?